# FORTRAN Error: BUS ERROR/SEG while printing a variable

Tags: fortran

All,

I am working on estimation of a physical variable for my research and I ran into an odd issue. I already know the roots and differences between bus error and segmentation fault. But the problem is that, when I am printing a four dimension variable like this somewhere:

```
PRINT *, RH(1,1,1,1)
```

I am able to get reasonable value.
But, again, the same command in a loop leads to an error. Sometimes it shows me bus error and sometimes SEG one.

- The variable has never been modified from the first PRINT command until the
  second one.
- I am running this on a cluster machine with 32GB RAM. So, RAM capacity should suffice.
- RH is  defined as  `REAL*8  :: RH(IIPAR,JJPAR,LLPAR,25)        !RH`

I would be thankful if someone could help on this.

Best,
Amir

Comment: Try recompiling your code with all run time checks turned on and rerunning. What does that tell you? Almost certainly you've written to memory that you shouldn't have, but without a full program it's impossible to tell. And real*8 isn't, and has never been, standard Fortran, please learn about kinds - see e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/838310/fortran-90-kind-parameter

Comment: Thanks Ian, I recompiled with -heap-arrays -g -traceback -check bounds

Comment: Other flags are: ifort -w -O2 -auto -noalign -convert big_endian

Comment: But, it doesn't report anything. SEG happened in MAIN_ Line 1

Comment: Please edit your question with more info, especially some complete compilable code. Read [ask] and [mcve]. It is important that you edit the question, because it is now hidden among old inactive posts.